# Tool for cleaning up / formatting JavaScript Code by alphabetizing property and method names

Tags: javascript, formatting

Does such a thing exist?

Lets say I have legacy code like this:

```
            var self = this;

            self.B_methodName = function (item) {
                return service.doSomeMoreWork(item);
            };
            self.A_methodName = function (model, cb) {
                return service.doWork(model).$promise.then(cb);
            },
            self.C_MethodName = function (model, cb) {
                return service.create(model).$promise.then(cb);
            }
```

I would want a shortcut that I could run that would rearrange the method names in alphabetical order like this:

```
            var self = this;


            self.A_methodName = function (model, cb) {
                return service.doWork(model).$promise.then(cb);
            },
            self.B_MethodName = function (model, cb) {
                return service.create(model).$promise.then(cb);
            }
            self.C_methodName = function (item) {
                return service.doSomeMoreWork(item);
            };
```

If not, has anyone implemented anything similar for a text-editor they use, or has tips on how to go about it?

Comment: Does that alphabetical order really matter?

Comment: Not in the example case but if I inherit a file with lots of methods written out of order then it can take a long time to track them down. When I create the file myself I always try to keep my methods in order but when you take over someone else's work it's not possible.